# How to get a doctrine loop to find the number of grouped records

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, symfony-1.4, doctrine-query

I am working on a query that is returning all published records, and grouping and ordering them by the latest updated_version.

Then I am filtering that result to show the results that were updated in the last 24 hrs, week, and month.

All works dandy. However, I would like to add the condition that if no records have been updated in each of these three date criteria, then to echo "No records have been updated".

I am curious if I can isolate these groups in the query and check against that, or possibly set a variable in the loop. The issue with the loop is, I can get the 0 result condition in the loop, but because it is checking INSIDE the loop, I get an echo of "No results found" for each record in the loop.

OK, Here is the query:

```
//return all unpublished records
$draftEntries = Doctrine::getTable("foo")
    ->createQuery()
    ->where('published = 0')
    ->groupBy('updated_at')
    ->orderBy("updated_at DESC")
    ->execute();
```

And the loop:

```
$message .= "These profiles were edited within the last 24 hours: \n";                      
    foreach ($draftEntries as $entry) {
        $currentDay = substr($entry['updated_at'], 0, 10);
        $condition = false;
        if($currentDay == $today) {
            $condition = true;
            $message .= $entry['last_name'] . ", " . $entry['first_name'] . "\n"; 
        else {
            $message .= "There were records updated yesterday";
            echo $condition;
        }
    }
```

This is just on of the three loops, but I think you get the gist of my intention. Obviously, this is the loop that returns:

There were records updated yesterday.
There were records updated yesterday.
There were records updated yesterday.
...

which is not desired.

So, from the query, can I check to see if the groupBy is greater than 0?
Surely I can do this without setting up three queries to get a result right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved this. If there is a better answer, let me know.

I didi not try to isolate the group in the query, I just used a few conditional statements in the loop:

```
//Edited in the last 24 hours
    $message .= "<p>These profiles were edited within the last 24 hours: </p><ul>\n";
    $lineitem = "";                     
    foreach ($draftEntries as $draftentry) {
        $currentDay = substr($draftentry['updated_at'], 0, 10);
        if($currentDay == $today) { 
            $listpiece .= $draftentry['id'];
            $listpiece .= "&profile_type=faculty'>".$draftentry['last_name'] . ", " . $draftentry['first_name'] . "</a> / Edited by: ".$draftentry['last_updater']."</li> \n"; 
            $lineitem .= $listpiece;
        }
    }
    if ($lineitem == "") {
        $message .= "No edits were made.";
    }
    else {
        $message .= $lineitem;
    }
```

I am concatenating the `$message`, but I needed to formulate a condition for what gets included in the `$message` outside the loop. `$lineitem` represents a single entry in the loop. It is instantiated outside the loop, then can be passed data according to the if statement inside the loop.

SO far, it works pretty well.